# how to add the event dynamicly in js

Tags: javascript, html

When I get some json data I want to display them in the page :

code :

```
    function update(){

      for(far i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        var l=document.createElement("li"); 
        document.getElementById("ul_con").appendChild(l);
        l.onclick=function(){
          alert ("id:"+data[i].id);
        }

      }
}
```

However,I get the error: data[i]i is not defined.

any way?

BTW,since I post this question on my phone,so I can not format the code well.l hope someone can do me a favor.

UPDATE:

```
    function update(){

      for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        var l=document.createElement("li"); 
        l.tindex=i;
        document.getElementById("ul_con").appendChild(l);
        l.onclick=function(){
          alert ("id:"+data[this.tindex].id);
        }

      }
}
```

This code works also,but I wonder why the "data" can be used when the click event occur while the "i" can not?

Comment: i can't be used at the time of the click because it's value has changed by the loop by the time the click happens.  data can be used if it's value is still valid at the time the click happens.  This code solves the problem of i by freezing the value you want when it stores it as l.tindex.  You have to remember that the click happens long after the assignment to l.onclick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the onclick function is called, it is at a much later time than when you hooked up the event handler and the data and i values may no longer be what they were at the moment you hooked up the function so you cannot rely on them.  In fact, the i value is guaranteed not to be the same because it will have advanced because of subsequent interations of the loop.  The data value may or may not be valid depending upon the rest of your code.

You can freeze them for use within the event handler like this:

```
function update(){
    for(far i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        var l=document.createElement("li"); 
        document.getElementById("ul_con").appendChild(l);
        l.onclick=(function(mydata, index){     // define function that gets called at assignment time
            // variables mydata and index are available here in this scope
             return function() {
                alert ("id:"+mydata[index].id);
            };
       })(data, i);   // pass data and i into the inner scope
    }
}
```

By doing it this way, the first function(data,i) is executed at the time the onclick handler is assigned.  This evaluates data and i and establishes their value for the use in the inner function via the function closure.  See [this writeup](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/referencedvariables.html) for a description and more examples.  Since `data` is an array, you are not making a copy of it here (it is passed by reference) so you will have to make sure that its values are preserved until the time of the click handler (though it will not go out of scope because this closure preserves it).  The value of i is copied in the function parameter so you don't have to worry about the outer loop changing the value of i.

It's a little less confusing and more easily understandable when it looks like this, but if you study the two, you can see that they are really the same thing, the first example just has an inline nameless function definition:

```
function processMyClick(mydata, index) {
    return function() {
        alert ("id:"+mydata[index].id);
    };
}

function update(){
    for(far i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        var l=document.createElement("li"); 
        document.getElementById("ul_con").appendChild(l);
        l.onclick=processMyClick(data, i);
    }
}
```

If all you need is a couple pieces of data out of that data structure, then you may want to just put it on the DOM object itself like this:

```
function update(){
    for(far i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        var l=document.createElement("li"); 
        document.getElementById("ul_con").appendChild(l);
        l.myId = data[i];
        l.onclick=function() {alert(this.myId);};
    }
}
```

When putting data on DOM objects, you do have to be careful about cleaning up appropriately to avoid potential memory leaks or circular references if you create/destroy a lot of these and run in older browsers.

Comment: so,any idea tohandlethese?  in fact,need the id it the item when it is clicked,i also need other property of the items,for example,the name,address,location and etc .all these property come from the serverside. so how can i bound these data to the element？  i don't want to save these data in the HTML tag

Comment: I added an example of how to do this and a reading reference for hwo to deal with this general type of issue.

Comment: hi,thanks for your suggestions,so does it mean i have to make the data array global?  also,i wonder if the is any way to bound the data item to the element directly,just like the jquery.data.

Comment: The data item does not have to be global.  It will stay in scope (e.g. not get garbage collected) as long as this click handler is defined on this element because the function closure holds a reference to it and keeps it alive.  You will have to not mess with the data in the "data" variable if you expect it to work for the click handler.

Comment: I added a third way that adds the id onto the DOM object.  It's just an object so it can take any new attributes you want (as long as they don't conflict with normal DOM operation).

Comment: thanksfor your patient,and the link you provided is wonderfu!

Comment: :hi,jfriend00 ,though this question is solved,but I have some confusion,I update the post,can you have a check?

Answer (score 1):

When the `onclick` event fires, the `data[]` array is out of context. You'll need to use `this` instead ie

```
l.onclick=function(){
   alert ("id:"+this.id);
}
```

Comment: but the element 'l' does not have the attribute 'id'. how can i use it